# Laravel: Passing a value of 0 back to controller from frontend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a boolean field that is represented by `0` and `1` in my database.

```
if ($request->input('submitted')) {
       // do code
 }
```

This has been working because it's only been setting the field to `1` (true) but now there's a new flow that can revert the submission.
It has not been setting it back to `0` when I pass the value `0` in from the frontend and I assume it's because that condition is getting skipped since `0` would eval to null.

Is the best way to handle it:

```
if (isset($request->input('submitted'))) {
           // do code
}
```

or would strictly checking against null work better:

```
if ($request->input('submitted') !== null) {
     // do code
}
```

Comment: I would use if ($request->has('submitted')). If that's a checkbox!!!

Answer (score 0):

The simply approach parse your input to a boolean.

```
if ((bool) $request->input('submitted')) {
```

This will create the following results. Therefor removing your edge case.

```
(bool) "1" // true
(bool) "1" // false
```

An alternative approach is to use inbuilt `PHP` filter, it will parse a lot of cases more notably "true" and "false" to true and false.

```
if (filter_var($request->input('submitted'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {
```